# Missing System.IO.Compression.Native.dll in .NET 8 leads to error when using GZipStream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, gzip, zlib

I have recently upgraded a .NET 6 application (ASP.NET Core MVC) to .NET 8. Testing the upgrade worked perfectly fine on my development machine. But when testing this on an external machine (which has .NET 8 SDK installed), a function that would extract data from zipped stream fails with the following:

```
var inputStream = new MemoryStream(gZippedFile);
FAILS --> var archive = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
```

> System.IO.Compression.ZLibException: The underlying compression
> routine could not be loaded correctly.
> ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.IO.Compression.Native' or one of its dependencies:  The
> specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)  at
> System.IO.Compression.ZLibNative.ZLibStreamHandle.InflateInit2_(Int32
> windowBits)  at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateInit(Int32
> windowBits) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at
> System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateInit(Int32 windowBits)  at
> System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor(Stream stream,
> CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Int32 windowBits, Int64
> uncompressedSize)  at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream..ctor(Stream
> stream, CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)  at [...]

I have observed that this "System.IO.Compression.Native" assembly was never directly referenced in any of the .NET 6 or .NET 8 deps.json file. In both, I can only find the same reference to System.IO.Compression assembly:

```
 "System.IO.Compression/4.3.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.1.0",
      "System.Buffers": "4.5.0",
      "System.Collections": "4.3.0",
      "System.Diagnostics.Debug": "4.3.0",
      "System.IO": "4.3.0",
      "System.Resources.ResourceManager": "4.3.0",
      "System.Runtime": "4.3.0",
      "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.3.0",
      "System.Runtime.Handles": "4.3.0",
      "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.3.0",
      "System.Text.Encoding": "4.3.0",
      "System.Threading": "4.3.0",
      "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.3.0",
      "runtime.native.System": "4.3.0",
      "runtime.native.System.IO.Compression": "4.3.0"
    }
  },
```

Unfortunately, I have no control over the system that creates the compressed file.

I have a hunch that I am missing something completely obvious, but I cannot put my finger on it :-(

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: What OS has "dev" and what OS has "external" machine ? how did you deploy on "external" machine ?

Comment: Both Windows 10 22H2, deployed via file copy of the output of 'dotnet publish "src\\Web\\Web.csproj" --runtime win-x64 --self-contained --output "dist"'

Comment: What happened if you re-install the System.IO.Compression.Native from the Nuget package? Besides, how you tested it ? Directly running it from the VS or host it inside the IIS to test?